Unable to build packages on Pi
I am currently building a bot using ros 2 humble on a raspberry Pi 3b+ (1 gb) running ubuntu server (22.04). I'm facing issues when it comes to building certain packages. Certain packages start building and then at a certain percentage get stuck with no progress at all. Could someone please guide me on why I'm facing this issue and how I could rectify the same.
Thanks in advance!

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!
Please edit your question to include the instructions you followed and the corresponding errors you are getting.
Thank you for your cooperation.

are you thinking that we somehow know what you are doing and what errors you get?

That's almost for sure the pi running out of RAM. Build with -j1 and if even that doesn't help, configure some swap space.

This is probably due to RAM limitations on the RPi. Once the build is halfway done the RAM is full causing the build to crash or stop. You can try using setting make flags to use a single thread while building to reduce system load.
export MAKEFLAGS="-j 1 -l 1"
colcon build --executor sequential

This could work but will increase the build time largely.
Similar error is mentioned here for building microros package
https://github.com/micro-ROS/micro_ros_setup/issues/601 refer to this link for more info on the make flags https://answers.ros.org/question/368249/colcon-build-number-of-threads/.
